# Python 2.7: This code isn't working. Any Ideas?

Tags: python

Its supposed to be a simple fun password cracker but whenever I run it it does nothing. There is apparently no error. Any ideas on what is wrong???

```
number = 0
password = 200
i = 10

while i == 10:
    if number != password:
        number = float(number) + float(1)
while i == 10:
    if number == password:
         print("Password found, Password is: {1}".format (number))
```

Thanks!

Comment: It might be useful for you to [edit] the question and write out in pseudo code what you think the program is doing. Just talking it out might help you spot some parts of the code that aren't needed, or aren't doing what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks problematic:

```
while i == 10:
    if number != password:
        number = float(number) + float(1)
```

You're saying while i == 10... yet the value of i never changes in your code and is going to be an infinite loop.

It's hard to tell what you really want, but you might be looking for something like this:

```
>>> number = 0
>>> password = 200
>>> while number != password:
...     number += 1
... 
>>> print("Password found, Password is %d" % number)
Password found, Password is 200
```

Maybe get rid of the whole "i = 10" business

Comment: Wow thanks! I'll be sure to remember this. Me and my friend couldnt figure it out. We're kinda new to the python business ig. ty again!

Comment: BTW you can use the print format method as mentioned in the other answer. I just like using the %d or %s technique as it reminds me of C and many other languages

Comment: ok. Thanks alot, once again

Answer (score 2):

Your code is entering an infinite loop since `i==10` will always be true.

```
while i == 10:
    if number != password:
        number = float(number) + float(1)
```

This loop runs forever since you never redefine `i` within it

Additionally, the string formatting in the print is incorrect since there is no element of index `{1}`.  Try `{0}` instead.

```
print("Password found, Password is: {0}".format (number))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It would be great if you could a short sentence to your first part which points out, that the loop will not be left and be running forever.

Comment: Good point, added for clarity!

Comment: Thanks alot! Im surprised I didnt notice this v.v Thanks for the help!